# Proper notation for common contiguous sequences within two series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, time-series

Say sequence $A=(1,2,3,4)$ and sequence $B=(1,2,3,4,5)$. How would you formally denote a new sequence of all common subsequences in $A$ and $B$ of length greater than or equal to 4? The resulting sequence in this example would simply be $(1,2,3,4)$. However, I must represent this concept for much longer $A$ and $B$ sequences with many overlaps.

Edit*: As came up in responses, this challenge is close to [Longest Common Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem), but the intention is to only consider *contiguous* subsequences (and not just those with the same relative order, as is the case in LCM). Also, I must somehow represent *all* common subsequences and not just the longest. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is this what you want: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem (Key difference being "substring" not "subsequence")

Comment: @MiloBrandt Not OP, but yes.

Comment: Thank you, doesn't this only denote the longest contiguous substring but not all of them?